# Select 'i' element inside child span

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div id="groupList">
  <div class="element">
    <span class="label label-default" data-index="0">
      big big big big big big big name!.txt
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `<i>` is an icon of font-awesome to remove the `.element`.

If I select in jQuery:

```
$(document).off('click').on('click', '#groupList .element > span', function()
```

it works. But I want to execute the function only when the user press the icon inside the i. Something like:

```
$(document).off('click').on('click', '#groupList .element > span > i', function()
```

but that doesn't work. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest, given the HTML:

```
// Select the <i> element with the 'fa' and 'fa-times' class-name,
// that exists within an element matching the '.element' selector';
// when that <i> element is clicked:
$('.element i.fa.fa-times').on('click', function () {

  // remove the closest ancestor element matching the
  // '.element' selector:
  $(this).closest('.element').remove();
});
```

```js
$('.element i.fa.fa-times').on('click', function () {
  $(this).closest('.element').remove();
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="groupList">
  <div class="element">
    <span class="label label-default" data-index="0">
      big big big big big big big name!.txt
      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).

Comment: Yes, this closest() I didn't knew, and is very good in this case... I'll accept your answer as it was very complete and gave me new knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){

    $(document).off('click').on('click', '#groupList .element > span i', function(){

    alert();
    });

});
```

Check out [FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/r2ynpuj5/)

Comment: loll!! I tried this, but didn't note that I'm executing a function using 'this', so didn't worked because in fact the 'this' was the i element. But now I put an alert and I saw it alerting, so in fact it wasn't an event issue, but a scope...